# Equivalent of curl code in requests using POST and authentication

Tags: curl, python-requests

For the following curl call (which works as expected)

```
curl -D - -X POST -s -d 'user=USER&password=PASS' -H 'Accept: application/xml' "url"
```

I tried

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/xml'}
response = requests.post("url", auth=('USER', 'PASS'), headers=headers).text
```

But got 
   Response [401]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in curl `-d` means key-paired value based POST data(`content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). So it should be:

```
params = {'user': 'USER', 'pass': 'PASS'}
headers = {'Accept': 'application/xml'}
response = requests.post("http://localhost/post.php", data=params, headers=headers).text
```